# Finding number of common terms in two AP

Tags: sequences-and-series

Series 1 - $17,21,25.....417 $

Series 2 -  $16,21,26......466$

**My Work -**

For Series 1 general term $(t_n) = 4n+13$

for series 2 general term $(t_r) = 5r+11$

$4n +13 =5r+11 $

value of  $n$ in terms of $r = \frac{5r-2}{4}$

now $n$ and $r$ both are integers $\mathbb{Z}_+$

$r = 2,6,10 \cdots$ so that $n =\mathbb{Z}_+$

calculating the last term of $r$

$417 = 5r+11 $
therefore max value of $r = 81.2 ---> 81$

$r = 2,6,10 ....81 $

$81 = 2 +(x-1)4
x= 20.75 , x = 20$

so there are *$20$ common terms* between two series but the answer given is **$22$ terms**.

Comment: I confirm. They have 20 common terms $20k + 1;\;1\leq k\leq 20$

Comment: Do you wish to say answer given at my book is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure of the limits on the series?  $417$ is a lot smaller than $461$.  If the $417$ was supposed to have been $457$ then the series line up better and the correct answer would be $22$.

Comment: Sorry actually the correct last term of two series was 417 for series 1 and 466 for series 2

Comment: Well, I suspect it was supposed to say $457$ for the top series.  That would add $421$ and $441$ to the intersection.

Comment: @lulu  No,  it's 417 only

Comment: Sure, but then I suspect that there was a typo in the source.   Seems silly for the first series to cut off so far before the second, and this lines up with the official answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$4n+2(5-4)=5r$$

$$\iff4(n-2)=5(r-2)$$

$\iff\dfrac{5(r-2)}4=n-2$ which is an integer

As $(5,4)=1,4$ must divide $r-2$

So, $r-2=4t$(say) where $t$ is any integer $\implies n-2=5t$

So, max$(16,17)\le4(5t+2)+13\le$min$(417,461)$

$\iff-1<-4/20\le t\le396/20<20$